# Random variable defined by two different geometric distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I have the random variable $Y$ which takes on two different types of geometric distributions as follows
\begin{equation}Y =
\begin{cases}
GEO(q_{1}) \;\; &\text{with probability } p_{1} \\
GEO(q_{2}) \;\; &\text{with probability } p_{2}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
I need to determine what $\mathbb{P}(Y=x)$ is, the probability mass function. Let $X\sim GEO(q_{1})$ and $Z\sim GEO(q_{2})$. Does the following then hold?
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(Y=x)=p_{1}\cdot\mathbb{P}(X=x)+p_{2}\cdot\mathbb{P}(Z=x)
\end{equation}
I have tried to look through all my notes and online but I can't seem to find a similar situation to the one I have now.

Comment: This is called a mixture distribution. And your equation holds, by law of total probability

Comment: Assuming $p_1+p_2=1$, then yes.

Comment: Yes indeed $p_{1}+p_{2}=1$. Sorry, I forgot to mention that. Thank you both.